# ViewController appears mulitple times when creating a navigationController programmatically in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uicollectionview

I have been creating my app completely from scratch programmatically, **without using Storyboards**.

My app is integrated with Firebase, and uses Facebook login.

My setup is fairly simple:

> 1. Launch the app -> takes you to the first VC called `WelcomeViewController`.
> 2. There is a check that happens in the `viewDidLoad` method to see if a user is already signed in and exists. If there is, it sends you straight to the second VC called `FilmsViewController`
> 3. The `FilmsViewController` is a collectionViewController that displays films. The user can press a film, and it takes them to more information about that film.

**(For reference, I am already signed in with Facebook in my app)**

I have a current issue, where when step 2 above happens, it transitions to the `FilmsViewController`, but it does it like 2 or 3 times. So you see the new VC appear like 2 or 3 times, then the content loads. If you press the `Back` button in the nav bar, it takes you back through the 2 or 3 viewControllers that it loaded before taking you back to the `WelcomeViewController`.

I have set my views up as follows.

In `AppDelegate.swift`:

```
var window: UIWindow?
var navController: UINavigationController?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    navController = UINavigationController()
    let firstViewController: WelcomeViewController = WelcomeViewController()
    self.navController!.pushViewController(firstViewController, animated: true)

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.rootViewController = navController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true

}
```

In the `WelcomeViewController` in the `viewDidLoad`:

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.addStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in

        if let user = user {

            // User is signed in.
            // Direct the user to the home screen

            let toFilmListVC = FilmsViewController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(toFilmListVC, animated: true)

        } else { ...
        }
}
```

I have looked loads for a solution - and nothing. I've only found one post on this issue, where someone said the solution was to change the class name of that controller, which I have already done and it didn't change anything.

Can anyone help me resolve this, please? Thank you.

Comment: This may not directly answer your question, but this YouTube channel has a ton of helpful tutorials on _not_ using storyboards, this link is specifically for firebase as well - https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL0dzCUj1L5JEfHqwjBV0XFb9qx9cGXwkq

Comment: @JasonM. This is the guy who encouraged me to start coding without Storyboards!! I have followed exactly as he has done, and no joy, which is what makes this more frustrating. Thanks though! Brian's channel is fantastic and anyone else seeing this, check him out!

Comment: looks like your addStateDidChangeListener is called more than one times in the beginning. Did you set a breakpoint there to analyze this? Iam as well a little bit confused how you set the WelcomeController to the Nav Controller. You should initialize the navController with the welcomeController as RootViewController. Well but if it works :D. So check the listener and you will see ;)

Comment: what you can do is, check in the listener before pushing, if your current controller is visible in the view, if iam not wrong you can use self.view.isVisible or like that. Ehm, and try using a weakified self :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `addStateDidChangeListener` is probably being called multiple times.

You should modify it to check whether a `FilmsViewController` has already been pushed, to prevent pushing another one:

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.addStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in

    if let user = user {

        // User is signed in.
        // Direct the user to the home screen

        // Only push one FilmsViewController onto the navigation stack!
        var shouldPush = true
        if let navigationController = self.navigationController {
            for viewController in navigationController.viewControllers {
                if viewController is FilmsViewController {
                    shouldPush = false
                }
            }
        }

        if shouldPush {
            let toFilmListVC = FilmsViewController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(toFilmListVC, animated: true)
        }
    } else { ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the above solutions works, but to make it look extremely simple.
here is the code i wrote in my project.

```
let someController = SomeController.someController()
if !(self.navigationController!.viewControllers.contains(someController)){
   self.navigationController?.pushViewController(someController, animated:true)
 }
```

only push the controller to navigation bar if the controller is not exist.